# How to sort result of groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with my finances in it. As a sample see:

```
{'Transaction Date': {0: Timestamp('2022-05-04 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2022-05-04 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2022-04-04 00:00:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2022-04-04 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2022-04-04 00:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2022-04-04 00:00:00'),
  6: Timestamp('2022-04-04 00:00:00'),
  7: Timestamp('2022-04-04 00:00:00'),
  8: Timestamp('2022-04-04 00:00:00'),
  9: Timestamp('2022-01-04 00:00:00')},
 'Transaction Description': {0: 'School',
  1: 'Cleaner',
  2: 'Taxi',
  3: 'shop',
  4: 'MOBILE',
  5: 'Restaurant',
  6: 'Restaurant',
  7: 'shop',
  8: 'Taxi',
  9: 'shop'},
 'Debit Amount': {0: 15.0,
  1: 26.0,
  2: 48.48,
  3: 9.18,
  4: 7.0,
  5: 10.05,
  6: 9.1,
  7: 2.14,
  8: 16.0,
  9: 11.68}
```

I can print a summary for each month with:

```
reportseries = df.assign(ym=pd.to_datetime(df['Transaction Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m')).groupby(['ym','Transaction Description' ] )['Debit Amount'].sum() 
print(reportseries)
```

This gives me:

```
ym       Transaction Description
2022-01  shop                       11.68
2022-04  MOBILE                      7.00
         Restaurant                 19.15
         Taxi                       64.48
         shop                       11.32
2022-05  Cleaner                    26.00
         School                     15.00
Name: Debit Amount, dtype: float64
```

How can I sort each group so I get this instead?

```
ym       Transaction Description
2022-01  shop                       11.68
2022-04  Taxi                       64.48 
         Restaurant                 19.15
         shop                       11.32
         MOBILE                      7.00
2022-05  Cleaner                    26.00
         School                     15.00
Name: Debit Amount, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets reset the index then sort values in `Debit Amount` in desc order and use the new sorted index with `iloc` to reposition elements

```
reportseries.iloc[reportseries.reset_index().sort_values(['ym', 'Debit Amount'], ascending=[True, False]).index]
```

Alternatively you can restructure/update your existing code to get the result directly

```
cols = ['ym', 'Transaction Description']
ym = pd.to_datetime(df['Transaction Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m')

reportseries = (
    df.assign(ym=ym)
    .groupby(cols, as_index=False)['Debit Amount'].sum()
    .sort_values(['ym', 'Debit Amount'], ascending=[True, False])
    .set_index(cols)['Debit Amount']
)
```

##### Result

```
ym       Transaction Description
2022-01  shop                       11.68
2022-04  Taxi                       64.48
         Restaurant                 19.15
         shop                       11.32
         MOBILE                      7.00
2022-05  Cleaner                    26.00
         School                     15.00
Name: Debit Amount, dtype: float64
```